# MySql variable sequential calculation with group by do not work properly

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

A table as like following and the query give desired result.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, @a:=@a+(col2+col3) col4
FROM test
JOIN (SELECT @a:=0)t

col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
-------------------------
a    |  1   |  1   |  2
b    |  2   |  0   |  4
c    |  3   |  0   |  7
a    |  0   |  2   |  9
```

But when I use group by it do not work properly. Do you have any good solution?

```
SELECT col1, SUM(col2)col2, SUM(col3)col3, @a:=@a+SUM(col2+col3) col4
FROM test
JOIN (SELECT @a:= 0)t
GROUP BY col1

    col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
    -------------------------
    a    |  1   |  3   |  4
    b    |  2   |  0   |  2  << It will be 6
    c    |  3   |  0   |  3  << It will be 9
```

First row fetched correctly. but row2 and row3 did not calculate previous row col4 value as like previous example. I can not understand where is the problem!

Comment: What is your expected result from second request ?

Comment: Of Course group is going to group...

Comment: in your example they are grouped col1, they are distinct

Comment: @Imane: It is very simple sense that the col4 is a calculated field and do sum with previous record of col4 and current row of col2 and col3 which is shown in first result. but in second result it do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it worked for me :)

```
SELECT col1, col2,col3, @a:=@a+(col2+col3) col4
FROM (select col1,sum(col2)col2,sum(col3)col3 from test group by col1) as tes
JOIN (SELECT @a:= 0)t
```

I made a fiddle for you :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b3ac/44

Hope it helps ;)